# Входная строка при удалении файла C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp

Есть файл в базе. Его надо удалить через интерфейс. Код написан, но где-то во входной строке допущена неточность. Стоит нажать на заветную красную кнопку удаления файла, как выпадает ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть процедура на sql:

```html
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION metrolog.pmsystems_del_msqq_doc(p_user_name character varying, p_file_id integer)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
--  Удаление(обнуление) ссылки на файл в указанной таблице
DECLARE
  v_user_id integer;
BEGIN
  v_user_id := metrolog.paudit_getapuserid(p_user_name);    

  DELETE FROM skynet.link_msqq_docs_fbody WHERE file_id = p_file_id;
  DELETE FROM skynet.msystems_fbody WHERE file_id = p_file_id;

END;
$function$
```

Есть код на C#:

```
 protected void OnCallback_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.CallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] str = e.Parameter.Split(',');
        switch (str[0])
        {
            case "delete":
                try
                {
                    NpgsqlParameter[] pgsqlParams = { new NpgsqlParameter("p_file_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer) };
                    pgsqlParams[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(str[1]);
                    new Common(ASP.AppGlobal.PgSQLConn).EditData(pgsqlParams, Resources.PgSQLResources.DelMSQQdoc);
                    e.Result = "deleted";
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    throw new Exception(exc.InnerExc().Message);
                }
                break;
        }       
    }
```

p_file_id NULL при дебаге...!

И самое главное,  значение VAL идёт как UNDEFINED. Почему так?:

```html
function DelFileBody() {
    
    var val = ValidSelectFile();
    if (val && confirm('Подтвердите удаление файла?'))
        Callback_.PerformCallback('delete,' + val);
}
```

Функция DelFileBody вызывается при клике на красную кнопку Удалить:

```html
 <div class="spr_delete16" title="Удалить" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="DelFileBody(); return false;">
                        </div>
```

Информация об исключении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот в этой строчке `pgsqlParams[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(str[1]);` какое содержимое у `str[1]`?

Comment: И покажите полную информацию о исключении, включая вложенные исключения и трассировку стека

Comment: [0] delete [1] undefined . трассировку стека? прикрепил скриншот в конце.

Comment: то есть вот здесь `Convert.ToInt32(str[1]);` вы пытаетесь сконвертить `undefined`  в целое число?

Comment: вот тут `var val = ValidSelectFile();` val у вас чему равно? Оно должно быть числом

Comment: как сделать val целым? function ValidSelectFile() {
   
    var val = $("#listFiles :selected").val();
    if (!val) showMsg2('#msgUpload', "Вы не выбрали файл.", 'warning');
    return val;
}

Comment: Смотрте свои скрипты, обратите внимание на `listFiles`, значение, выбранное в нем, должно быть числом.

Comment: в скриптах всё ок, ибо на похожем проекте стоит в точности такая же функция и она работает

Comment: обратите внимание на `listFiles`, значение, выбранное в нем, должно быть числом

Comment: всё дело было в sql-процедуре, где id_file поменяли на file_id, добавив alias. Всё решилось. Спасибо!

Comment: Рад, что все решилось :)